# Mergesort on a linked-list using only one function, segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

I need to implement the function: `struct listnode * mergesort(struct listnode *data)`
My professor provided the main() function testing code. I only need to submit the mergesort function. He told us to do it in C or C++ but the test code main() he gave us is in C.

This is my code right now: 
I can compile it but when I run it, it crashes. I checked debugger and it gave me segmentation fault. I am also not really sure if this function is correct since I can't get past the testing point in the main().

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listnode { struct listnode * next;
                         long              value; } ;


struct listnode * mergesort(struct listnode *data)
{   int temp, finished = 0;
    struct listnode *tail, *head, *ahead, *bhead, *atail, *btail;
    if ( data == NULL )
        return;
    //Split
    ahead = atail = head = data;       // first item
    btail = head->next;         // second item
    while(btail->next != NULL)  // anything left
    {
    atail = atail->next;
    btail = btail->next;
    if( btail->next != NULL)
        btail = btail->next;
    }
    bhead = atail->next;        // disconnect the parts
    atail->next = NULL;

    //sort
    mergesort(ahead);
    mergesort(bhead);

    //merge
    if(ahead->value <= bhead->value)  // set the head of resulting list
        head = tail = ahead, ahead = ahead->next;
    else
        head = tail = bhead, bhead = bhead->next;

    while(ahead && bhead)
        if(ahead->value <= bhead->value)  // append the next item
            tail = tail->next = ahead, ahead = ahead->next;
        else
            tail = tail->next = bhead, bhead = bhead->next;

    if(ahead != NULL)
        tail->next = ahead;
    else
        tail->next = bhead;
    return(head);
}


int main(void)
{
   long i;
   struct listnode *node, *tmpnode, *space;
   space =  (struct listnode *) malloc( 500000*sizeof(struct listnode));
   for( i=0; i< 500000; i++ )
   {  (space + i)->value = 2*((17*i)%500000);
      (space + i)->next = space + (i+1);
   }
   (space+499999)->next = NULL;
   node = space;
   printf("\n prepared list, now starting sort\n");
   node = mergesort(node);
   printf("\n checking sorted list\n");
   for( i=0; i < 500000; i++)
   {  if( node == NULL )
      {  printf("List ended early\n"); exit(0);
      }
      if( node->value != 2*i )
      {  printf("Node contains wrong value\n"); exit(0);
      }
      node = node->next;
   }
   printf("Sort successful\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

---

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and deal with them!! `if ( data == NULL) return;` **must** return a value. And `mergesort(ahead); mergesort(bhead);` are ignoring the values returned.

Comment: Ah yes! I was told by someone that just doing `mergesort(ahead); mergesort(bhead);` doesn't work but I'm not sure how to make it return the the head of the new lists. Can someone please show me what I should do?

Comment: First you should have | ahead = mergesort(ahead); | , | bhead = mergesort(bhead); | . Next you need to clean up the merge code. Using a pointer to pointer can simplify creating a merged list: | node * pNew = NULL; | , | node **ppNew = &pNew; | , then set *ppNew = pointer to lower of two nodes, and advance ppNew using | ppNew = &((*ppNew)->next); . Next advance pointer to lower of two nodes = *ppNew;

Comment: @rcgldr Thanks, I now have ahead = mergesort(ahead) and bhead = mergesort(bhead). Also, I'm so sorry! I'm pretty amateur at coding so for the things you said about pointer to pointer, I'm not sure if you can clarify it a bit because I don't really understand. Right now, I can't figure out 
    `if(data != NULL)
    ahead = atail = head = data;       
    if(head->next !=NULL){
    btail = head->next;         
    }
    if(btail != NULL)
    while(btail->next != NULL)` The debugger keeps giving me an error at `while(btail->next != NULL)`

Comment: @Jia - see answer below for example function to merge lists. Rather than go through several iterations of answers and questions, I posted example code for the merge list part using pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( data == NULL )
    return;
```

You should return NULL.

---

```
btail = head->next;         // second item
while(btail->next != NULL)  // anything left
{
```

If btail is set to head->next. If head->next is NULL, you're trying to check in the loop NULL->next != NULL which isn't a thing.

---

```
if( btail->next != NULL)
    btail = btail->next;
}
```

You need to check if btail is NULL before you check ->next. Just above you are setting     btail = btail->next; so it could be set to NULL.

Also the loop above has the same issue, you need to check null before you do stuff with next.

---

There may be issues with the below code, but the above code needs way more error checking.

Comment: So I did `if(head->next !=NULL){
    btail = head->next;         // second item
    }`  and `if(btail != NULL)
    while(btail->next != NULL)  // anything left
    {` but the debugger still gives me an error at the while loop even though I checked if `btail != NULL`

Comment: sorry for late reply. You need to check if head != NULL, then head->next != NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Example function to merge two already sorted lists using pointer to pointer. Since your'e only allowed a single function, you'll have to merge this logic into your mergesort() function. If this is homework, it may seem like you had too much help, but I'm not sure how else to explain the ideas shown in this example.

```
NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                      /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;                   /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    while(1){
        if(pSrc1 == NULL){
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            break;
        }
        if(pSrc2 == NULL){
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            break;
        }
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            continue;
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            continue;
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}
```

Comment: Can a function be made inside another function? For example is it possible to make a mergelist function inside the `struct listnode * mergesort(struct listnode *data)` ?

Comment: You could make a macro, but since the stated goal is a single function, that might be considered bending the rules. You can just use similar code in the existing function, using ahead for pSrc1, and bhead for pSrc2, and pDst/ppDst or pNew/ppNew for the merged list.